# execution time of the algorithm to build model

Tags: time, execution

I want to know time taken to build a model. But, when running the algorithm multiple times to build the model I got multiple time taken to build the model.  Why different? Why not constant time taken to build the model?  Even time taken fluctuated for the same algorithm how can I compare time taken for two different algorithms.

```
Double start_time=System.nanoTime()/Math.pow(10, 9);                     
KMeansModel clusters = KMeans.train(rdd.rdd(), numClusters,numIterations,init_mode,30);        
System.out.println("time taken to build model: "+((System.nanoTime()/Math.pow(10, 9)) - start_time));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can measure model training time as an average of multiple runs. E.g. run the training 100 times and take the total time / 100. This should provide more consistent values between runs (as a batch), assuming the algorithm doesn't use much randomness during training.

If you're using spark, it might be useful to enable spark's loginfo to see stats per run. For kmeans, you should see among others:

```
logInfo(f"Initialization with $initializationMode took $initTimeInSeconds%.3f seconds.")
logInfo(f"Iterations took $iterationTimeInSeconds%.3f seconds.")
logInfo(s"KMeans converged in $iteration iterations.")
```